# Make Google Video Chat (in Gmail) distinguish between two USB webcams

Tags: google-talk, chat

I have two USB-connected webcams attached to my machine.  Unfortunately, while GChat recognises that both exist, it doesn't seem to be able to distinguish between them.  It has picked the wrong one by default; when I go into the Chat settings and select the other one from the dropdown (both are labelled as "USB webcam"), it continues to show the output of the first - it doesn't even give me the option to 'save changes' (I'm guessing because they're both named the same to it).

As far as I know, I am not accessing it in another window.

Any ideas?

Comment: Edit request: *to -> *two

Comment: @Joe Sorry I missed that.  Corrected.

Comment: Can you correct this issue by using the Google Talk video chat functionality?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming this is based on flash.  You can either remove the camera you dont want and use the one you have.

From my understanding you can't save, so it remember but you should be able to select the correct one every time. pain in the butt though.